# how to create a jdbctemplate connecting to sql server with TLS?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I made it work using a property as the following in the application.properties,

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://sql0001.us.com;databaseName=grade;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;trustStore=c://git//t.jks;trustStorePassword=*****`

And a jdbctemplate bean is created. However, the password is not supposed to appear in the property file. I need to feed it with a separate property in the command line. Is there a property like
`spring.datasource.url.trustStorePassword`?